Geometry Nodes: How to check menu switch node values?
Is it possible to check if a specific menu item has been selected? If it has, a boolean should be set to "True." If other menu items are selected, the boolean should be set to "False." I want to conditionally execute something after the Menu Switch Node in certain cases.
Alternatively, it would be great if there was a way to read which menu ID is currently selected. That way, I could set conditions based on that.
Additional infos:
I know you can use the index node in the tree internally. In my situation I would like to provide a readable menu to the user to choose from. Internally I need index values that represents the individual menu positions to compare between them. That's my problem.
Is there something like this available?


You have to use Index Switch instead of Menu Switch. Otherwise you cant use the input at multiple place.

As @Lutzi already said, you need an Index switch instead of a Menu Switch because you cannot use a Compare node with the Menu data type.
However, if you do not want to completely change the geometry to something else when index 2 is chosen (which would make no sense because then you could simply use that geometry for the third input instead of a cylinder), then you do not have to use another Switch node.
The Set Position node like many other nodes has a Selection input. So you only need to plug the Index from the Group Input into a Compare node set to Integer and choose to compare with 2. This means, the Result is true when you choose the cylinder and false for the other objects.
Plugging the Result into the Set Position's Selection input will then only affect geometry when the Index is 2:

//EDIT: Now that I know you want a readable menu, I made a small change to my setup. The problem still is you cannot use the Menu data type in a Compare node, however instead of switching Geometry with the Menu Switch, you can set it to Integer. Then you have readable menu items that choose the integer which will then be used as index for the Index Switch which will finally determine the Geometry:


Thank you for your answers. I know you can use the index node in the tree internally. In my situation I would like to provide a readable menu to the user to choose from. Internally I need index values that represents the individual menu positions to compare between them. That's my problem.

@ChristophWerner It wasn't really obvious that you want to keep a readable menu, since you mention you want to read which menu "ID" is currently selected and you even added the integers 0, 1, 2 in the screenshots. I've edited my question to add a solution for that at the end.

Thank you a lot, Gordon. This is what I was looking for.  I didn't know the index switch is that flexible. I guess I have to dive more in... Sorry for the misunderstanding at the beginning. I've changed my question text above to be more clear to other users.
